# Do Yahoo & Gmail smtp server uses implicit or explicit SSL?

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp

I'm trying to write the send mail program using System.Net.Mail which is the latest in C# to send an email.  Unfortunately this only support explicit(TLS/SSL) and not implicit(SSL), the predicated library System.Web.Mail on the other hand supports implicit SSL.

After Googling and searching on StackOverflow, I came across a very useful answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082216/gmail-smtp-via-c-sharp-net-errors-on-all-ports/3845907#3845907)

So now I'm able to send my test email to yahoo and gmail using their smtp server below.  However, i can't confirm if Yahoo uses implicit SSL and Gmail uses explicit, please help:

Yahoo: 
smtp server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
port: 465

Gmail:
smtp server: smtp.gmail.com
port 465 or 587

Comment: Was my answer below acceptable?  If so, please accept as answer.  If not, please let me know what I can do to clarify or improve it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply David, I was just trying to do more research on the whole explicit and implicit ssl.  You answered my question, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article contains your answer:

http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/john-waters/2011/03/15/the_different_flavors_of_secure_smtp_and_ssl

Both services support both implicit and explicit SSL:

"Even though Implicit SSL is not standardized, you may as well get used to it. Yahoo mail uses it on port 465, as does Google gmail. But both these servers also provide Explicit  SSL support on port 587, so you can chose what fits your needs."