# Cannot send email with SMTP in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp

So, I am working on windows Forms and trying so send email with smtp. 
Here is a Code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, text);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 465;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);

try
{
    client.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("Mesage has benn sant");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failure while sending message");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

When I run this Code I am getting Following Error:

> "Failure sending email".

When I changed port to 587 I have got following:

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication REquired".

So why I cannot send email ? Can someone explain me that ?

I have changed port to 25 and have sent mail from hotmail( I have replaced "smtp.gmail.com" with "smtp.live.com"), not from gmail. And it works. Seems it's something wrong with gmail.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3845907/101087

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMail SMTP via C# .Net errors on all ports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082216/gmail-smtp-via-c-sharp-net-errors-on-all-ports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make your code work by adding the following three lines and making change in the gmail account setting:

```
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential (from, password);
```

In addition to the above changes, it turns out, you also need to update your google account settings and allow less secure apps.

I learned about this on this thread: [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope, it didnot helped. It gives me still same Error

Comment: Did you change the security setting in your Google account

Comment: You have to enable " allow less secure apps"

Comment: I have enabled it and now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help! Can you upvote it to show that this answer helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the port to 25.

Also, the arguments for `client.Credentials` are supposed to be your username and password to login with. For example...

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

Comment: I have changed port to 25 but it gives me still this error: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication REquired"

Comment: Did you change the credentials to a valid Gmail account?

Comment: On my gmail account I have got following message : "  
Hi Dave,
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account Username@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standard"

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding quickly. [This thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/662568/why-blocks-gmail-my-postfix-relay) gives more insight and solutions about the situation.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Was able to fix it by disabling this security setting:

going to this link and turning on "access for less secure apps"

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHCXU.png)